# How to find Telegram groups by word in their posts?

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

I want to find all Telegram groups where a special word has been used. For example, I want to get all posts from ALL Telegram groups where word "Spider-Man" has been printed yesterday.

Can I achieve this with telethon library? And if I can, can you please provide an example of code how?

Comment: Yes, thats possible. What did you try to solve this ?

Comment: Asked this question here

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please read [ask]. Show us your code so we can help, we're not going to just provide you with it.